# Divide Git branch by files

Tags: git, github

Git Branch A has a number of files modified(about 50 files or so), which were modified over time and sometimes as in the same commit:

Example:

```
File A
File B
File C
File AA
File BB
File CC
File ZZ
```

I would like to split the file changes into two branches, File A, B, C, ZZ would be in Branch A, and Files AA,BB,CC, ZZ would be on Branch B. I need one common file.

Is there a way to do this? If so how?

Example:

```
Master --------\
                \
                 \- - - - -- Branch A (Files, A,B,C,AA,BB,CC, ZZ)

Goal:
Master --------\
               |\
               | \- - - Branch A (Files, A,B,C, ZZ)
               |
               |-------- Branch B (Files, AA,BB,CC,ZZ)
```

Comment: You want to make it a single commit for each separate branch? Do you want to have a common ancestor revision for all the branches?

Comment: common ancestor revision if possible, if I am understanding you correctly.

Comment: What do you want to hold on the common ancestor?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you. I would like to keep my commit history in the new branch.

Comment: You can keep your messages and authors, but your hashes are going to change.

Comment: Is that going to cause any issues?

Comment: What's the recommended way to do this?

Comment: Not really a problem, It's just that your history is going to be modified is all. The fact that you're asking to do this means you intend to modify your history. it isn't a problem, just wanted to make sure that was clear to you. Human Readable history will appear untouched, but your hashes will change

Comment: The recommended way to do this is to avoid putting yourself in this situation. The modifications to the certain files should have been done on their own branches to begin with.

Comment: If the hash numbers change that's ok, as long as not other issues appear.  I agree with recommendation :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190166/discussion-between-oxymoron-and-user2012677).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Identify your common ancestor revision commit hash. This is identified with a red asterisk in all images below. I'm going to use `a9c146a09505837ec03b` as an example hash.

   a. `git show` or `gitk` can help with this
2. Checkout a new branch with that hash as your head (i.e. `Branch B`)

   a. `git checkout -b Branch_B a9c146a09505837ec03b`
3. checkout the specific files from `Branch A` onto your new branch `Branch B`.

   a. i.e. `git checkout Branch_A -- "A.file"`

or if you would like to keep your commit messages you can use `git cherry-pick`, but only in the case that the changes to your files are not mixed within the same commit. If you have to split the commit up then your best using the example above with `checkout`. You will loose your history, but if you really need to retain that, you can `git checkout` on specific commit hashes too and walk through your history bring over the file mutations in order. A sever headache for sure.

Please keep in mind, your hashes ARE going to change.

repeat steps 2 & 3 as necessary for the amount of branches you would like to create. Avoid making changes to the same content across multiple branches, this will lead to a merge conflict.

---

Some Examples:

[image: Current State]

[image: Example with no common files]

[image: Example with common file changes]

Comment: How did you draw the images?

Comment: I used Microsoft Paint.

Answer (score 1):

One approach I like for the "case that the changes to your files are not mixed within the same commit" is to create a new branch at the tip of the branch I want to split and use `rebase -i` to drop irrelevant commits.

i.e.

With branch_a checked out run:

```
git checkout -b branch_b
git rebase -i <common ancestor commit>
```

For my use cases, most often `<common ancestor commit>` is the name of the main branch I have checked out, e.g. `main` or `develop` or something like that off of which I started working.

Comment: This feels like the inverse of a cherrypick approach? But also could be tricky to perform if you're not 100% sure of the relevant commits